# Why "favorite off-site resource"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I just noticed the end of this reason:

> - Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Why favorite *off*-site resource? Does that mean the if I asked for everyone's favorite *on*-site resource I'd be in the clear?

Comment: Your favourite on-site resource would be a dupe..

Comment: I just think about asking "What is your favorite question on SO?".

Comment: @JohannesKuhn - "Overly Broad"

Comment: @johannes primarily opinion based

Comment: Ok, and now we have an answer.

Comment: "unclear what you are asking" (seriously). I think it means they don't want answers such as "spam.com" or "mysiteisbetterthanyours.com".

Comment: Is "favourite" ever **not** primarily opinion-based? (i.e. why are there 2 close reasons for the same thing)

Comment: @Dukeling I just find it odd that we specify off-site, that's all.